# Arithmetic series, find the first 80 natural numbers which sum when divided by 31 has a remainder of 17

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The question is as follows:

Find the first 80 natural numbers which sum when divided by 31 has a remainder of 17
So I tried to come up with a sum formula which is like this, I came up with everything from this point on, I don't know if it's correct:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{80}kx=1x+2x+...+80x=s$$
I came up with this I don't know if it's correct, or if I understood the question correctly. So the next step I took was:
$$a_1=1*x$$
$$a_n=80*x$$
$$n=80$$
$Y=$ divided sum
$$$$
$$$$
Then I took the sum formula that has $a_n$ in it. I divided $\frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$ with 31 and added 17 to the quotient
$$Y+17=\frac{80}{74}(x+80x)$$
Forward from here I got confused.

Comment: what are $x$ and $s$? I do not see how the formula relates to the question, there is not even a $17$ or a $31$ anywhere.

Comment: I divided $\frac{n}{2}(a_1+a_n)$ with 31 and added 17 to the quotient

Comment: I ment the very first one.

Comment: let $x\in\mathbb{N}$ be the starting number of the desired 80 squential natural number. Try to calculate  $\sum_{n=0}^{79}(x+n)$.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "the first 80 natural numbers." Generally, that would mean the numbers $1,2,3,\cdots 80$ but evidently, it means something else here, something that is unspecified in the question. For example, it could mean the first 80 *consecutive* natural numbers. Could you specify exactly what is meant by "the first 80 natural numbers"?

Comment: This is the question that is written in the textbook, I also do not understand the question very well. As I understand it means that they have to be consecutive, but I don't know if that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

**hint**

$$u_n=a+nb$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{79}u_n=$$
$$a+(a+b)+(a+2b)+...+(a+79b)=$$
$$80a+b(1+2+...79)=$$

$$80a+b\frac{79(79+1)}{2}=$$
$$=80.a+3106.b$$

Comment: Can you explain this expression

Comment: @BiliDebili Which one ?

Comment: the second one and third